# Same pop up window with meta referesh

Tags: javascript, jquery, popup, meta-tags

I want to open page [pop up] on page load and my page has meta referesh tag

```
<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="300">
```

I have to pop up the window every 5 minutes. I am using the below code

```
     <script type="text/javascript">
        window.open("http://google.com"); 
</script>
```

It is working fine but it is giving me the new IE window in every 5 minute. I want that if that URL is already opened it will just referesh the browser.

I brief, in every 5 minutes I want pop window should be refreshed rather than open new window each and every time.

Any help?

I am perfectly fine with the solution either in Javascript, JQuery or server side coding.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pass along a name in your window.open method, like this:

```
window.open("http://google.com", "mysite_p")
```

The popup will then be opened in the same popup - refreshing the page in the popup. 
If no popup window is open yet, one will be opened.

As a side note, refreshing the page that is opening the popup every 5 minutes to refresh/open the popup window is probably not the most efficient solution (depending on what else is happening).

You may want to look into using a timeout function the launch the window.open instead. See [setInterval](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_setinterval.asp) method.

Answer (score 0):

set a cookie on page load and check if the cookie exist before executing `window.open("http://google.com");`

This will help you open the popup only once.